# How to retrieve date from database using java

Tags: java, sql, datetime

I need to retrieve the date and time from a database. My code correctly retrieves the date and time but when I use `toString()` it adds a ".0" to the end of the time. How can I avoid this?

IE: date on database is `2013-03-05 11:05:25`

When I retrieve it and try to convert it to a String it becomes `2013-03-05 11:05:25.0`

```
 r.getTimestamp("mydate").toString();
```

Comment: I believe you want to use SimpleDateFormat to construct a date as you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to display the date in any fashion you want

```
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(r.getTimestamp("mydate"));
```

This should display it how you are after.

**EDIT:**

You have said your method is not returning the object as a timestamp or date, you need to put it into a date format first to use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String in = r.getTimestamp("mydate"));
Date d = sdf.parse(in);
```

Comment: I did it but it shows an error : cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: what does r.getTimestamp("mydate")) return? this would work if it returns a timestamp (i just ran it on a timestamp and it works). if it is returning an object should you cast the object to a timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

Don't think about the value on the database as being a *string* value at all. Think of it being a point in time. (I'm assuming it really *is* a `TIMESTAMP` field or something similar.)

If you want to format it in a particular way, do so - but 2013-03-05 11:05:25 is the same *point in time* as 2013-03-05 11:05:25.0... it's just using a different string representation.

Comment: yeah it is the same but wy is it adding the .0 to the end of it?

Comment: @DanielMorgan: That's just how `Timestamp.toString()` works. It's not "adding" it - it's just using a format of "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff" as documented.

Comment: Jon is absolutly correct have a look at the toString doco for timestamp - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually remove the ".0" you could just do this. Where "s" is the string object with the extra 2 characters.

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
```

Comment: thanks but I need to know how to avoid it not how to remove it

Comment: substring manipulation isn't a particularly nice way to do things.